# URL Mapping help needed

Tags: c#, url-rewriting, url-routing

I Have url like 
"http://www.mysite.com/aspx/downloaddoc.aspx?J01001"

I want this to be easily accesible by typing out: 
"http://www.mysite.com/Whitepapers/J01001"

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Thanks in Advance

Shashi.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this [URL rewriting module](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-url-rewrite-module/) (IIS7). If you don't have IIS7, you might want to check out this very helpful article on [URL rewriting](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx) by Scott Guthrie. Or use [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/).